# What is the signature of the Clang compiler in the ELF?

Tags: header, clang, signature, elf, clang++

I have several binaries compiled with `gcc/g++` and others compiled with `clang/clang++`.

So far i have tried:

```
strings -a ./myBinary | grep -i clang
objdump -s --section .comment ./myBinary
readelf -p .comment ./myBinary
```

and each one of this command fails to recognize the binaries produced by `clang`, and each file produced by Clang is recognized as produced by `gcc` and basically all my binaries are produced by the same compiler according to this tools.

Does Clang puts the same signature as GCC ? How i can get informations about what compilers have generated that binaries ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362914/can-i-compile-a-function-with-gcc-and-then-use-it-with-clang

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I compile a function with gcc and then use it with clang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362914/can-i-compile-a-function-with-gcc-and-then-use-it-with-clang)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's a duplicate of [stackoverflow.com/questions/43523698/clang-appears-to-use-gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43523698/clang-appears-to-use-gcc)

It seems that if you link against a glibc built by GCC, the latter takes the credits.