# clang appears to use gcc

Tags: gcc, clang++

When I compile a simple hello world program using clang, in the comments of the elf64 file I still find information related to GCC. Why? I'm using clang not gcc.

I'm using ubuntu 16.04.

```
username@ubuntu:~$ clang++ -stdlib=libc++ test.cpp 
username@ubuntu:~$ objdump --full-contents --section=.comment a.out 

a.out:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of section .comment:
 0000 4743433a 20285562 756e7475 20352e34  GCC: (Ubuntu 5.4
 0010 2e302d36 7562756e 7475317e 31362e30  .0-6ubuntu1~16.0
 0020 342e3429 20352e34 2e302032 30313630  4.4) 5.4.0 20160
 0030 36303900 636c616e 67207665 7273696f  609.clang versio
 0040 6e20342e 302e3020 28746167 732f5245  n 4.0.0 (tags/RE
 0050 4c454153 455f3430 302f6669 6e616c29  LEASE_400/final)
 0060 00                                   .               
username@ubuntu:~$
```

test.cpp is:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
std::cout << argc << std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

I also ran

```
username@ubuntu:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config c++
[sudo] password for username: 
There are 2 choices for the alternative c++ (providing /usr/bin/c++).

  Selection    Path                     Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/g++              20        auto mode
* 1            /usr/bin/clang++-libc++   5         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/g++              20        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 
username@ubuntu:~$
```

Is this ok? why?

Comment: You should check out clang source code as well. It is quite interesting ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you're linking with a C runtime (from Glibc) built with GCC, and the linker is merging the two together.

```
$ clang++ -c --stdlib=libc++ test.cpp
$ objdump --full-contents --section=.comment test.o

test.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of section .comment:
 0000 00636c61 6e672076 65727369 6f6e2034  .clang version 4
 0010 2e302e30 20287461 67732f52 454c4541  .0.0 (tags/RELEA
 0020 53455f34 30302f66 696e616c 2900      SE_400/final).  
$ clang++ --verbose test.o
 "/usr/bin/ld" --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o a.out /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.1/../../../../lib64/crt1.o /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.1/../../../../lib64/crti.o /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.1/crtbegin.o -L/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.1 -L/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.1/../../../../lib64 -L/usr/bin/../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.1/../../.. -L/usr/bin/../lib -L/lib -L/usr/lib test.o -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.1/crtend.o /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.1/../../../../lib64/crtn.o
$ objdump --full-contents --section=.comment /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.1/../../../../lib64/crt1.o

/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.1/../../../../lib64/crt1.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of section .comment:
 0000 00474343 3a202847 4e552920 362e332e  .GCC: (GNU) 6.3.
 0010 31203230 31373033 303600             1 20170306.     
$ objdump --full-contents --section=.comment a.out

a.out:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of section .comment:
 0000 4743433a 2028474e 55292036 2e332e31  GCC: (GNU) 6.3.1
 0010 20323031 37303330 3600636c 616e6720   20170306.clang 
 0020 76657273 696f6e20 342e302e 30202874  version 4.0.0 (t
 0030 6167732f 52454c45 4153455f 3430302f  ags/RELEASE_400/
 0040 66696e61 6c2900                      final).
```

My system has slightly different versions from yours, but you can see that the Clang-compiled object only has the Clang identifier in it, the C runtime object has the GCC identifier in it, and the final binary has both.

Comment: `It's because you're linking with a C runtime (from Glibc) built with GCC`. Is it something you have control over? Can you build a program under Linux without using GCC at all?

Comment: Of course you can. Linux kernel can be built with clang since 2020 and gcc can be compiled with clang.